# Is there disadvantages of including and creating all classes object dynamically?

Tags: class, object, autoload

I have a folder with all classes and I want to write a script which will include and create an object of each class.
I would like to know if there is any disadvantages of doing it?

Please let me know if it is not clear and I will try to write more about it.

The reason why I'm asking is because, my site have a lot of data models (for articles, users, etc.) I don't want to include/exclude everytime every class manually, so I want to write a script to include all classes.

Will it affect on performance?

Should I include only those classes which I will use on the page?

Since I will include classes automatically, I was thinking of creating their object at the same time.

Can creating the objects affect on performance?

Comment: Question is "why"? Sure you can do it (Assuming your programming language supports it), but only worth the effort if there is a good reason to do it!

Comment: I answered to question "why" above. I hope it is clear )